API handler unable to access middleware's context value in Golang
I am trying to append value of my ID to context in my auth middleware, which verifies user and pass it to my API handler.
I want to verify JWT in middleware and pass the id to handler for further use.
I am trying to access the context with value in handler but not able to access it but at a same when I access the same context with value (attached to request) in the middleware itself ,I am getting the value. Full reproducable example is available here; selected code and logs follow:
route:
addProductDistHandler := middlewares.Auth(client, log)
r.Handle("/add-product-distributor", addProductDistHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handlers.AddProductDist(log, client))))

auth middleware code :
logger.InfoLog.Printf("user.ObjectID %T",user.ObjectID)
logger.InfoLog.Printf("user.ObjectID %v",user.ObjectID)

// Add user ID to request context
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userIDKey, user.ObjectID) // Assuming user.ObjectID is a primitive.ObjectID
r = r.WithContext(ctx)
logger.InfoLog.Printf("context : %T => %v",ctx,ctx)
distID, _ := r.Context().Value(userIDKey).(string)
logger.InfoLog.Printf("distID : %s",distID)
// Call the next handler
next.ServeHTTP(w, r)`

handler's code :
distID, ok := r.Context().Value(userIDKey).(string)
if !ok {
    logger.InfoLog.Println("userIDKey is not of type string or is nil")
    // Handle the case where userIDKey is not of type string or is nil
    helpers.EncodeJSON(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "userIDKey is not of type string or is nil", nil)
    return
}

logs
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 cookie retrieved successfully
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 ObjectID("66757f98606b94271a05cd24")
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 user.ObjectID string
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 user.ObjectID 66757f98606b94271a05cd24
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 context : *context.valueCtx => context.Background.WithValue(type *http.contextKey, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type *http.contextKey, val [::1]:8000).WithCancel.WithCancel.WithValue(type mux.contextKey, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type mux.contextKey, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type middlewares.contextKey, val 66757f98606b94271a05cd24)
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 distID : 66757f98606b94271a05cd24
INFO                    2024/06/21 23:36:46 userIDKey is not of type string or is nil

In short, I want to access value appended in middleware func to request with the help of context into my handler and I am unable to do so
I tried variety of things but failed

Can you please turn your code into a reproducible example? (something like this, which works :-) ).

thanks @Brits so much. but what did i do wrong?

Dont know sorry (thats why Im asking for a reproducable example, suspect the issue is in codr you did not include).

https://github.com/mahirjain10/go-error
sorry for the late reply . I added these code (a simple implementation what i am doing) but still getting error.

In package middlewares you have:
type contextKey string
const userIDKey contextKey = "userID"`
//...
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userIDKey, "helloworld")

and then in package handlers you have:
type contextKey string
const userIDKey contextKey = "userID"
//...
distID := r.Context().Value(userIDKey).(string)

So you are storing an entry in the context with the key middlewares.contextKey("userID") and then attempting to retrieve it with handlers.contextKey("userID"); these are two different keys (the types differ), so you will not get the value.
Using a private type as a map key can be useful because it prevents collisions (both packages can have a map key called "name" and these will refer to different values). However in this case that is not what you want. To fix this either use a string as the key, export the key constant, or provide a getter function in middlewares.
The below example demonstrates this playground:
package main

import (
    "play.ground/foo"
)

type contextKey string

const userIDKey contextKey = "userID"

func main() {
    test := make(map[any]string)
    test[userIDKey] = "blah123" // using key of type main.contextKey 
    test[foo.UserIDKey2] = "blah987" // using key of type foo.contextKey

    foo.Test(test)
}

package foo

import "fmt"

type contextKey string

const userIDKey contextKey = "userID"
const UserIDKey2 contextKey = "userID2"

func Test(test map[any]string) {
    fmt.Println(test[userIDKey]) // blank line
    fmt.Println(test[UserIDKey2]) // blah987
}

output:

blah987

Here is a slightly different version where the type is public (closer to what you did).

thank you so much ,I am really grateful.
